# How to get the free Hard drive space using batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to get the free HDD space using batch file. it returns the space in bytes but i need it in GB.
I tried converting but there are some limitation in batch that doesn't allow operations on very large number.

This is my script.

```
for /f "tokens=2" %%S in ('wmic volume get DriveLetter^, FreeSpace ^| findstr "^C:"') do set freeSpace=%%S
echo %freeSpace%
```

I also tried to eliminate the last 9 digits (GB) but it is very inaccurate. for example. if the free space is 180 GB, it shows, 200GB.

Is there any other way i can do this?

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun/learn.

In windows, the `%windir%\system32\wbem` folder contains the xsl files used for output format of wmic. And wmic lets you indicate a xsl file (`/format` parameter). So, i make a copy of `textvaluelist.xsl` file from wbem folder, and changed it to get what you need.

At end, i generated this `myFormat.xsl` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output encoding="utf-16" omit-xml-declaration ="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/" xml:space="preserve"><xsl:apply-templates select="//INSTANCE"/></xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="INSTANCE" xml:space="preserve"><xsl:apply-templates select="PROPERTY|PROPERTY.ARRAY|PROPERTY.REFERENCE"/></xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="PROPERTY" xml:space="preserve"><xsl:value-of select="@NAME"/>=<xsl:apply-templates select="VALUE"><xsl:with-param name="type"><xsl:value-of select="@TYPE"/></xsl:with-param><xsl:with-param name="name"><xsl:value-of select="@NAME"/></xsl:with-param></xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="PROPERTY.ARRAY" xml:space="preserve"><xsl:value-of select="@NAME"/>=<xsl:apply-templates select="VALUE.ARRAY"><xsl:with-param name="includequotes">true</xsl:with-param><xsl:with-param name="type"><xsl:value-of select="@TYPE"/></xsl:with-param></xsl:apply-templates></xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="PROPERTY.REFERENCE" xml:space="preserve"><xsl:value-of select="@NAME"/>=<xsl:apply-templates select="VALUE.REFERENCE"></xsl:apply-templates></xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="VALUE.REFERENCE">"<xsl:apply-templates select="INSTANCEPATH/NAMESPACEPATH"/><xsl:apply-templates select="INSTANCEPATH/INSTANCENAME|INSTANCENAME"/>"</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="NAMESPACEPATH">\\<xsl:value-of select="HOST/text()"/><xsl:for-each select="LOCALNAMESPACEPATH/NAMESPACE">\<xsl:value-of select="@NAME"/></xsl:for-each>:</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="INSTANCENAME"><xsl:value-of select="@CLASSNAME"/><xsl:for-each select="KEYBINDING"><xsl:if test="position()=1">.</xsl:if><xsl:value-of select="@NAME"/>="<xsl:value-of select="KEYVALUE/text()"/>"<xsl:if test="position()!=last()">,</xsl:if></xsl:for-each></xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="VALUE.ARRAY"><xsl:param name="type"/>{<xsl:for-each select="VALUE">
        <xsl:apply-templates select=".">
            <xsl:with-param name="type">
                <xsl:value-of select="$type"/>
            </xsl:with-param>
            <xsl:with-param name="includequotes">true</xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">,</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>}</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="VALUE">
    <xsl:param name="type"/>
    <xsl:param name="name"/>
    <xsl:param name="includequotes"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$type='string'">
            <xsl:if test="$includequotes='true'">"</xsl:if><xsl:value-of select="."/><xsl:if test="$includequotes='true'">"</xsl:if>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$type='char16'">
            '<xsl:value-of select="."/>'
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$type='uint64' and $name='FreeSpace'">
            <xsl:value-of select="format-number(. div 1073741824,'#0.00')"/>GB
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Just little modification to the original from Microsoft. At the end of it, there is a modification to handle the case of the FreeSpace property, returning it converted to GB.

Now, to use it,

```
wmic volume where "driveLetter='c:'" get capacity,freespace /format:"c:\pathTo\myFormat.xsl"
```

It generates

```
Capacity=241173401600
FreeSpace=153.61GB
```

As you can see, since the rule was included only for the `FreeSpace` property, only it is converted, while `Capacity` is not.

I know, much complication for a simple task, but as said, just for fun (first time i edit a xsl)

Comment: +1, ***Very*** nice! I've been tempted to fool around with custom WMIC formats, but never had the courage. Now that I've seen your success, I may take a stab at it some day :-)

Answer (score 0):

Well - let's put it this way. You've elected yourself to put all the worms back in the can, OK?

Commercially, manufacturers prefer to express the size in Gigabytes - for which they invoke the authority of SI (Systeme Internationale) and use a factor of 10**9.

The computer industry uses powers of 2, so SI introduced the well-known term Gigibyte (or so I am reliably informed) which means 2**30.

(SI also wants you to refer to "10 Kilogram" or "10 metre", not "10 Kilograms" or "10 metres". Yeah - a directive assiduously followed only by terminology turkeys)

So - GigAbytes for manufacturers because the number is bigger, and hence better than the GigIbytes number used in the industry.

All of this is of course outside of the experience and comprehension of Miss Longlegs, the boss's sechetary, who will inform you in no uncertain terms that she has 200Gb, not 180 - so you are RONG!

Although it's logical to use Gig**i**bytes, you are really pushing the proverbial to get the self-declared "experts" outside of IT to understand - and even most insiders don't know the "official" terminology. Their diction makes the difference inaudible and were you to write it, so few people are aware of the correct terminology (but so many convinced that they **ARE** aware) that you would simply be regarded as a **POR SPELA**.

BUT - if you really, really want to use the 2**30 definition:

Batch is limited to 2**31, so you would have to either use another tool (possibly invoked from batch to make it behave) or if you insist on staying in pure batch, perform your division by manually devising a substring-and-repeated-subtraction method, using long-division methodology.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of ways to get around the limitations.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set wmi=WMIC LogicalDisk Where DriveType='3' Get DeviceID,FreeSpace,Size^|Find ":"
for /f "tokens=1,3,4" %%a in ('"%wmi%"') do (
   call :GetUnit %%b ufree
   call :Convertbytes %%b !ufree! free
   call :GetUnit %%c usize
   call :Convertbytes %%c !usize! size
   Echo %%a Free space: !free! !ufree! of !size! !usize!
)

exit /b

:ConvertBytes bytes unit ret
setlocal
if "%~2" EQU "KB" set val=/1024
if "%~2" EQU "MB" set val=/1024/1024
if "%~2" EQU "GB" set val=/1024/1024/1024
if "%~2" EQU "TB" set val=/1024/1024/1024/1024
> %temp%\tmp.vbs echo wsh.echo FormatNumber(eval(%~1%val%),0)
for /f "delims=" %%a in ( 
  'cscript //nologo %temp%\tmp.vbs' 
) do endlocal & set %~3=%%a
del %temp%\tmp.vbs
exit /b

:GetUnit bytes return
set byt=00000000000%1X
set TB=000000000001099511627776X
if %1 LEQ 1024 set "unit=Bytes"
if %1 GTR 1024   set "unit=KB"
if %1 GTR 1048576  set "unit=MB"
if %1 GTR 1073741824  set "unit=GB"
if %byt:~-14% GTR %TB:~-14% set "unit=TB"
endlocal & set %~2=%unit%
exit /b
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `wmic` or `fsutil` to get the free space on a drive/volume.  My example uses `fsutil`.  You can do 64-bit math in a command prompt, but it is a bit complicated.  So, we'll let `cscript` handle that part (including rounding) via a VBS file (*eval.vbs*) with **one** line of code:

```
WScript.Echo Round(Eval(WScript.Arguments(0)), WScript.Arguments(1))
```

This batch-file gets the free space, passes it to the VBS script and echoes the free space to the console. You can eliminate the second `for` statement if you want the VBS script to simply echo everything to the console, but then the VBS script isn't reusable for other purposes.

```
@echo off

setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%i in ('fsutil volume diskfree c: ^| find /i "of free"') do set _free=%%i
for /f %%i in ('cscript //nologo eval.vbs "!_free!/1024/1024/1024" 2') do set _free=%%i
echo The C: drive has !_free! GB free

endlocal
```

Which returns the following on my computer:

```
The C: drive has 45.26 GB free
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for completion. And as the other answer, just for fun. Kids, this should not be done. No error check, just the concept: reduce a big storage value in bytes to a smaller storage unit.

```
@echo off

    call :reduceStorage 241173401600  value
    echo %value%

    call :reduceStorage 1024 value
    echo %value%

    exit /b

rem --------------------------------------------------------------------
rem Reduce input number by dividing it by 1024 as many times as needed

:reduceStorage size resultVar
    setlocal
    set "size=%~1"
    set "u="
    for %%u in (K M G T P E Z Y) do if not "!size:~5,1!"=="" (
            call :divide "!size!" 1024 size
            set "u=%%u"
    )
    endlocal & set "%~2=%size% %u%B"
    goto :EOF

rem --------------------------------------------------------------------
rem Divide a large number by a small (2E31) number
:divide number div resultVar
    setlocal
    set "num=%~1"
    set "d=%~2"
    set "a="
    call :length "%num%" len
    for /l %%l in (0 1 %len%) do (
        if defined num (
            set "a=!a!!num:~0,1!"
            set "num=!num:~1!"
            if !a! lss %d% (
                if defined res set "res=!res!0"
            ) else (
                set /a "r=!a!/%d%"
                set "res=!res!!r!"
                set /a "b=!a!-(%d%*!r!)"
                if !b! gtr 0 (
                    set "a=!b!"
                ) else (
                    set "a="
                )
            )
        )
    )

    endlocal & set "%~3=%res%"
    goto :EOF

rem --------------------------------------------------------------------
rem return the length in characters of a variable
:length string returnValue
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
    set "p=16384"
    set "s=%~1"
    for %%i in ( 8192 4096 2048 1024 512 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1 ) do (
        for %%j in (!p!) do if "!s:~%%j,1!"=="" ( set /a "p-=%%i" ) else ( set /a "p+=%%i" )
    )
    if not "!string:~%p%,1!"=="" set /a p+=1
    endlocal & set "%~2=%p%"
    goto :EOF
```